# When does garbage collection happen, between program start and program end?

Tags: garbage-collection, c++-cli

When does garbage collection happen, between program start and program end?

I am using C++/CLI, but this is more of a general question about garbage collection.
I am not sure if garbage collection may actually happen after the program is done,
that is after the process for your program is killed. Or maybe ALL garbage collection
is completed before the program ends?

Thanks

Comment: C++ doesn't have garbage collection at all. But in languages that have, yes, it happens, typically many times, between the start and the end of the program.

Comment: I meant C++/CLI ah sorry.

Comment: Worst-researched question ever.

Comment: There is no Garbage Collection in C++ in the same way as in C#.  Some people like to say that using static and RAII is a form of Garbage Collection.  I respectfully, but strongly, disagree.

Comment: @user2381422:  You got *two* downvotes for a poorly-formatted and poorly-researched question.  Quite generous, if you ask me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does C++ have a Garbage Collector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089147/does-c-have-a-garbage-collector)

Comment: Avoid using the [c++] tag for questions about managed code, it isn't very popular with C++ programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not implement any type of garbage collection.

If your application uses RAII objects, their resources should be collected through stack unwinding, whenever one of them goes out of scope (that is, when destructors get called at ends of scopes) or exceptions are thrown.

You can implement your own garbage collection separate from RAII implementations (for example, if you have a high-throughput thread that cannot afford to waste time waiting on delete calls, you can pass the pointers to a separate thread that will be responsible for deleting them). In that case, the answer is "depends how you implement it".

In applications implemented in languages supporting garbage collection, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @user2381422:  You could have said "Thanks for taking time out of your day to write this answer, but I made a mistake in my original post and this answer doesn't apply."  Or something else polite and appriciative.   But you didn't do that, instead you downvoted and yelled at the guy.  Not very nice.  Especially considering it was *your* mistake that prompted this answer.

Comment: That kind of attitude makes people *not* want to help you.

Answer (score 3):

A garbage collection is only triggered when you allocate memory.  In the specific case when the generation 0 heap doesn't have enough space to satisfy the request.  So no, you won't get one when your program terminates, that's not likely the place where you ever allocate anything.

There is a special secondary job performed by the GC, it also runs the finalizer for any objects that have one.  Finalizers take care of releasing operating system resources that are not memory.  Like file handles, fonts, device contexts, etc.  They normally run *after* a garbage collection for any collected objects, assuming you didn't otherwise dispose the object yourself.

The CLR *will* run those finalizers, just before the AppDomain unloads and your program terminates.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you don't know, and shouldn't know.  As far as your concerned it shouldn't matter, unless you are in an *extremely* memory constrained environment, but in these cases why are you using managed code in the first place?

As far as your question goes, when your researching, all the .NET languages share a runtime, so they have the same garbage collector.  .NET only sees the IL code; it doesn't care if you wrote it in C# or C++/CLI.  So you should probably search "when does .NET garbage collector run", which (first hit on google) leads one to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088757/when-does-the-net-garbage-collector-run).  Read a couple of the answers and you should get what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically GC run at start to build its managed memory representation based on all your CLI/.Net object your declared as static or global (not sure it's a possible with CLI)

During the execution GC track managed reference and if 1 is no longer referenced by your code he should clean it

```
  system::string^ st = gcnew system::string; //(1)
  st = gcnew system::string ; (2)
```

here as (2) overwrite the ref created by (1) the GC should take the ref(the memory) you create at (1) and put it in the list of the memory to free! 
Because I suppose It wait to have a kind of larger set of memory to clean before running something that can consume CPU and time slot!

it runs at the end to clean all the object you allocated with "gcnew". And all static and global.