# Why aren't static fields garbage collected in C#?

Tags: c#

In the book C#12 in a Nutshell, it is written:

> The heap also stores static fields. Unlike objects allocated on the heap (which can be garbage collected), these live until the process ends.

However, if we don't use the static field later in the code, I don't see why the garbage collector would not free the space it was using on the heap?

I think an example can make my question easier to understand:

```cs
using System;

public class MyClass
{
    // Static field
    public static int Counter = 0;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyClass.Counter++;
    }
    
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Counter);

        MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
        myInstance.MyMethod();
        
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Counter);
        
        // From this line onwards, MyClass will not be used, the MyClass object referenced by myInstance
        // can therefore be Garbage Collected now.
        // However, MyClass.Counter will not be Garbage Collected as it is a static field?!
        // The static field could be a "bigger object" than just an int, and it would be 
        // bad not to Garbage Collect it right?
        
        int number1 = 10;
        int number2 = 20;
        int sum = number1 + number2;

        Console.WriteLine($"The sum of {number1} and {number2} is {sum}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: _"However, if we don't use the static field later **in the code**"_ that is completely unrelated to an application's lifetime, though. And the Example is under-complex. Throw some loops and threading into it, maybe async, then reconsider.

Comment: Whether or not you use references to an object in your logic, it can't safely be garbage-collected as long as references to it *exist*.  And static references exist throughout the life of the application.

Comment: ^^ and even if that weren't the case, you couldn't infer the lifetime _from the code_ in close to all cases.

Comment: Especially if it's not marked `readonly`... it could be reassigned, and the no-longer-referenced *object* could be GC'd.

Comment: "Reflection" implies one can't simply eliminate properties that aren't referenced explicity in code. The "class definition" is a "contract" that can't be changed arbitrarily; even by GC.

Comment: @GerrySchmitz: Where did reflection enter the discussion other than being part of my name?

Comment: I understand your points but if it's hard to know if the static field will be used later, how is not hard to know if `myInstance` will be used later too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11199154/17034

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Local variables inside a method only "exists" as long as this method is running. When the method ends, all variables are gone. However, keep in mind that you have to separate between variables/fields which can reference objects and objects that can be referenced by variables/fields. So the variable `myInstance` will be "gone" at the end of the method, but the object which was created at `new MyClass()` might still exists (after the methods ends).

Comment: So the garbage collector will intervene at the end of the method?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28461652/328193, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088757/328193, etc.  Basically, "when does the garbage collector run in c#" is a searchable term with lots of information to be found.  In most cases you won't need to know or care when the garbage collector runs.  The underlying system is pretty good at taking care of that when it needs to.  And even in many cases where you *think* you need to know or control this behavior, chances are that's in response to a design problem in the code.

Comment: I wasn't addressing you (@madreflection). I'm "new". I assume if I don't address "you", I'm addressing the "OP". "REFLECTION" (AS IN .NET) uses "strings" for property names which would break if you arbitrarily remove "properties".

Comment: @madreflection. You're "rep" appears to come from trolling. .Net "reflection" is "one reason" you can't GC "unreferenced" properties.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection in C# is primarily concerned with reclaiming memory associated with object instances that are no longer in use. Since static fields are not tied to individual instances, they cannot be marked as "no longer used" and therefore cannot be retrieved.
They remain in memory for the entire life of the application because there is no easy way to tell if they will be used again.

### tl;dr;

Static fields don't fit within the GC pattern.

Comment: In *theory*, if the GC can infer that a field will never be accessed again, it could collect the value. But that is not done at the moment.

Comment: That mean that you can determine that a type (that may access the static field) will never be instantiated again. Not an easy task.

Comment: @Charlieface: Static fields can be accessed by reflection; there is no way to determine by program analysis whether a field will be accessed in the future or not.

Comment: @EricLippert Equally non-static fields can be, but then GC doesn't analyze them either. In some future alternate reality, we may get pre-compiled reflection with AOT compilation, so we could work out what would be reflected over.

Comment: @Charlieface, you can't access a non-static field (by reflection or by normal way) if you don't have a reference of the instance.

Comment: @Orace I meant that in theory GC could even collect a value that was still held by a field of an object you hold, if it knew you were never going to access that field again.